# Using javascript to rewrite input value adding "#"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to replace the content of the input entered by adding a "#" in front of it, but at the time of writing the spaces it does not work correctly.

```js
function mayus(texto) {
  var text = texto.value.replace('#', '');
  var words = text.split(" ");
  var newTexto = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > 0) {
      newTexto += "#" + words[i];
    } else {
      newTexto += " ";
    }
  }

  texto.value = newTexto;
};
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;">      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No clue what you are asking. What is the expected output?

Comment: do you want to put the # symbol before each word, or before the entire text??

Comment: hi , before each word @eduCan

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: Please define "_it does not work correctly_". Explain what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: I want to rewrite the input by adding "#" to each word in the beginning @Anthony

Comment: That's what the current code does. What's going wrong?

Comment: OK, I don't still understand very well your question, I tried with the Code Snippet and it replace all the spaces with the # symbol, the problem is that the spaces are removed???

Comment: thanks (y)   @Teemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify your function. First we look to see if the value already starts with a `#` using [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and if it does we return. If not, we then add it to the beginning.

```js
function mayus(texto) {
  let val = texto.value
  let result = val.split(' ').map(item => !item.startsWith('#') && item != '' ? '#' + item : item)
  texto.value = result.join(' ')
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yes but the problem is that I want to write many words and it only works for the first one.
I want to add "#" to each word after a space

Comment: Yeah I just saw that in your comment, I am fixing, give me one moment.

Comment: this have a little bug, 
it does not let me erase the space

Comment: Why is the input value always not empty?

Comment: Because you have a space `<textarea> </textarea>` It should be `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: no, i have using this html code

<textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso con detalles" required ></textarea>

and the space appears ... 
i have to delete to show placeholder u know why?

Comment: Your above code shows 6 spaces between the two tags, that is the only thing I can think of that would cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement should not be there, and you can actually simplify your entire method using a more functional approach. Also use the `input` event instead of the `keyup` event to prevent a visual delay.

```js
var previous

function mayus() {
  var texto = this.value
    .replace(/#/g, '') // removes ALL hashtags
    .split(/\s+/g)
    .filter(Boolean) // removes empty strings from array of words
    .map(function(word) {
      return '#' + word;
    })
    .join(' ');

  // add space if key was pressed and output would have been identical
  if (previous && texto === previous) {
    texto += ' ';
  }

  previous = this.value = texto;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required oninput="mayus.call(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```